# Create triangle with "1" " 0" by for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How can I write a program in Java to make the following triangle?

```
1
0 1
1 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Try to identify the pattern and show us some sample code to prove that you have spent some effort on it.

Comment: Answerers: please don't encourage these sorts of homework dumps by answering them. OP: please give this a try, and ask specific questions if you have them.

Comment: One approach is to begin by writing an easier program, then modify it to get the program you need. For example, the first try could ignore the use of different characters, and just generate a triangle of "1".

Comment: I am not encouraging. He is not asking for anything difficult here so since SO is not really a place where you talk, I am just giving a way to answer so he can read it and understand it instead of just giving suggestions that maybe are not helping.

Comment: C'mon ppl don't be that harsh! This dude has put some effort... in a sign-up process. :D

Comment: @Vakh It's obviously difficult for the OP, or they would have done it themselves. Giving the answer with no explanation and no hint as to how you got it -- if that's not encouraging a homework dump, I don't know what is. How is somebody supposed to learn if people like you let them hand in their assignments without thinking about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0 ; i < nLines ; ++i) {
    s = (i % 2 == 0 ? "1 " : "0 ") + s;
    System.out.println(s); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give you a solution, but there's some patterns you can see:

- The number of digits is the same as the number of the line, assumign it starts in 1. For example, in the first line, you have 1 digit; in the second you have 2 digits.
- If it's an odd line, the first digit is a 1; otherwise, it's a 0.
- You always switch between 0 and 1, until you've reached the number of the line.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CurvedZebraTriangle{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int n=5; 
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j< i; j++)
              System.out.print((i+j) % 2 == 0 ? "0 " : "1 ");

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

     }
}
```